# Can't select or click links on text elements in <a> tags

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, header, paragraph

I have coded my navigation bar however my links are not clickable nor am I able to highlight the text. I am not sure why... I have put them onto `<a>` tags and added `href="#"` but it still isn't clickable. I was maybe wondering if it was the `display: #` or `position: #` I have added in styling that may have caused this? I mean on my footer the `a` tag seems to be working perfectly.

Could someone have a look and see if you see anything unusual that I may of missed

```css
body{
    margin: 0;
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
/* Navigation */
.header{
    width: 100vw;
    height: 6vh;
    background: #111111;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
.header div{
    flex: 1;
}
.header-logo{
    padding-left: 5vw;
}
#header-logo{
    height: 4vh;
}
.header-nav{
    text-align: right;
}
.nav-container{
    padding-right: 5vw;
}
.nav-list1{
    font-family: Oswald;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 1em;
    display: initial;
    padding: 0.25vh 1.25vw;
}
.nav-list2{
    font-family: Oswald;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 1em;
    display: initial;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 5px;
    padding: 0.25vh 1vw;
    border-image: linear-gradient(bottom right, #c71d6f 0%, #e36a64 100%);
    -moz-border-image: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom right, #c71d6f 0%, #e36a64 100%);
    -webkit-border-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom right, #c71d6f 0%, #e36a64 100%);
    border-image-slice: 1;
}
.nav-list2:hover{
    background: linear-gradient(bottom right, #c71d6f 0%, #e36a64 100%);
}
/* End Navigation */

/* Slideshow */
.section1{
    background: url(files/home-slideshow-001.jpeg);
    height: 94vh;
    background-size: cover;
}
#overlay{
    font-family: Oswald;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 3vw;
    font-weight: 700;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
/* End Slideshow */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Home</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:400,500,600,700" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="header">
            <div class="header-logo">
                <a href="http://www.#.com">
                    <img id="header-logo" src="files/w-logo.png">
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="header-nav">
                <span class="nav-container">
                    <a class="nav-list1" href="http://www.#.com/home">Home</a>
                    <a class="nav-list1" href="http://www.#.com/home">About</a>
                    <a class="nav-list1" href="http://www.#.com/home">Services</a>
                    <a class="nav-list2" href="http://www.#.com/home">Contact</a>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="section1">
            <div id="overlay">
                <h1>header</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `#overlay` element has been *absolutely positioned* and *taken out of the normal document flow*, this causes the element to "sit above" the `.header` element, resulting in the observed behaviour.

Create a new *stacking context* by declaring a `position` property with the value of `relative` on `.header` so that a `z-index` property with the value other than `auto` can be declared, e.g:

```
.header{
    width: 100vw;
    height: 6vh;
    background: #111111;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    /* additional */
    position: relative; /* required to declare a z-index property */
    z-index: 1;
}
```

**Code Snippet Demonstration:**

```css
body{
    margin: 0;
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
/* Navigation */
.header{
    width: 100vw;
    height: 6vh;
    background: #111111;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    /* additional */
    position: relative; /* required to declare a z-index property and create new stacking context */
    z-index: 1;
}
.header div{
    flex: 1;
}
.header-logo{
    padding-left: 5vw;
}
#header-logo{
    height: 4vh;
}
.header-nav{
    text-align: right;
}
.nav-container{
    padding-right: 5vw;
}
.nav-list1{
    font-family: Oswald;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 1em;
    display: initial;
    padding: 0.25vh 1.25vw;
    color: white;
}
.nav-list2{
    font-family: Oswald;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 1em;
    display: initial;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 5px;
    padding: 0.25vh 1vw;
    border-image: linear-gradient(bottom right, #c71d6f 0%, #e36a64 100%);
    -moz-border-image: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom right, #c71d6f 0%, #e36a64 100%);
    -webkit-border-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom right, #c71d6f 0%, #e36a64 100%);
    border-image-slice: 1;    
}
.nav-list2:hover{
    background: linear-gradient(bottom right, #c71d6f 0%, #e36a64 100%);
}
/* End Navigation */

/* Slideshow */
.section1{
    background: url(files/home-slideshow-001.jpeg);
    height: 94vh;
    background-size: cover;
}
#overlay{
    font-family: Oswald;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 3vw;
    font-weight: 700;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
/* End Slideshow */
```

```html
<div class="header">
            <div class="header-logo">
                <a href="http://www.#.com">
                    <img id="header-logo" src="https://placehold.it/200x100">
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="header-nav">
                <span class="nav-container">
                    <a class="nav-list1" href="http://www.#.com/home">Home</a>
                    <a class="nav-list1" href="http://www.#.com/home">About</a>
                    <a class="nav-list1" href="http://www.#.com/home">Services</a>
                    <a class="nav-list2" href="http://www.#.com/home">Contact</a>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="section1">
            <div id="overlay">
                <h1>header</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You #overlay is covering your page, so you cannot click underneath it.

Answer (score 0):

You have a div with the id "overlay" that prevents clicks from getting to the link. It basically shields the underlying webpage from clicks.

You can solve this by either deleting the overlay or by lowering the overlay so the click events above it will still work. You can do this by adding some space to the "overlay" css "top" property.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to do navegation bar you should do it into a < nav > tag and them the  like this :

```
    <nav class="header-nav">
            <div class="nav-container">
                <a class="nav-list1" href="http://www.#.com/home">Home</a>
                <a class="nav-list1" href="http://www.#.com/home">About</a>
                <a class="nav-list1" href="http://www.#.com/home">Services</a>
                <a class="nav-list2" href="http://www.#.com/home">Contact</a>
            </div>
        </nav>
```

Other thing, you can add to the navbar a z-index property so it will always stay on top of other things.

Answer (score 0):

Try the code snippet attached, I have changed the following in the your snippet.

```
#overlay {
 position: relative;
}
```

and

since you want to remove text getting highlighted in  tag, you can use

```
text-decoration:none;
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
}


/* Navigation */

.header {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 6vh;
  background: #111111;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.header div {
  flex: 1;
}

.header-logo {
  padding-left: 5vw;
}

#header-logo {
  height: 4vh;
}

.header-nav {
  text-align: right;
}

.nav-container {
  padding-right: 5vw;
}

.nav-list1 {
  font-family: Oswald;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 1em;
  display: initial;
  padding: 0.25vh 1.25vw;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.nav-list2 {
  font-family: Oswald;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 1em;
  display: initial;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 5px;
  padding: 0.25vh 1vw;
  border-image: linear-gradient(bottom right, #c71d6f 0%, #e36a64 100%);
  -moz-border-image: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom right, #c71d6f 0%, #e36a64 100%);
  -webkit-border-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom right, #c71d6f 0%, #e36a64 100%);
  border-image-slice: 1;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.nav-list2:hover {
  background: linear-gradient(bottom right, #c71d6f 0%, #e36a64 100%);
}


/* End Navigation */


/* Slideshow */

.section1 {
  background: url(files/home-slideshow-001.jpeg);
  height: 94vh;
  background-size: cover;
}

#overlay {
  font-family: Oswald;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 3vw;
  font-weight: 700;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}


/* End Slideshow */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Home</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:400,500,600,700" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="header">
    <div class="header-logo">
      <a href="http://www.#.com">
        <img id="header-logo" src="files/w-logo.png">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="header-nav">
      <span class="nav-container">
                    <a class="nav-list1" href="http://www.#.com/home">Home</a>
                    <a class="nav-list1" href="http://www.#.com/home">About</a>
                    <a class="nav-list1" href="http://www.#.com/home">Services</a>
                    <a class="nav-list2" href="http://www.#.com/home">Contact</a>
                </span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="section1">
    <div id="overlay">
      <h1>header</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `<div id="overlay">` covers the page, you need to set `z-index` to make sure it's underneath